# Drawn centroid with function make_circle

Tags: qgis, centroids, geometry-generator

I'm using the following function to draw a circle at the centroid position of a layer of points grouped by the "ID" field and excluding NULL values:

```
make_circle(centroid(
concave_hull(
    collect(
        $geometry,
        group_by:=if (
            ID is NULL, 
            overlay_nearest (@layer, ID, filter:=ID is not NULL)[0],
            ID
        )
    )
    ,0.52
)
),0.83)
```

As you can see in the image I have also drawn with the diamond symbol the centroid with the expression `centroid(collect($geometry,group_by:=ID))`. And the problem is that the Expression that I use to draw the circle appears displaced:

[image]

If I make the following correction in the function, it seems to work but the circle of the NULL value appears again.

```
make_circle(centroid(

    concave_hull(
        collect(
            $geometry,
            group_by:=if (
                ID is not NULL, 
                overlay_nearest (@layer, ID, filter:=ID is not NULL)[0],
                ID
            )
        )
        ,0.52
    )
    ),0.83)
```

[image]

What correction would be necessary to make so that the symbol of the NULL value does not appear and, at the same time the position of the circles with value not NULL appear in the centroid position?

---

The expression in the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/469782/115) makes the NULL object disappear but to calculate the centroid I still consider the NULL object.

The expression that does calculate the centroid for non-NULL objects gives another position for the centroid:

```
make_circle(centroid(
concave_hull(
    collect(
        $geometry,
        group_by:=if (
            ID is not NULL, 
            overlay_nearest (@layer, ID, filter:=ID is not NULL)[0],
            ID
        )
    )
    ,0.52
)
),0.83)
```

I think this expression is correct when is used the instruction `group_by:=if (ID is not NULL`, but I would like it not to draw the circle object with NULL value.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the same expression for the centroid as you use as first argument in the the `make_circle()` function. Here's why:

1. The centroid of the collected points is not the same as the centroid of the concave hull.
2. Your expression `centroid(collect($geometry,group_by:=ID))` groups by `ID` and `ID=NULL` will create its own group, what you do not want.

So use this expression for the centroid:

```
centroid(
    concave_hull(
        collect(
            $geometry,
            group_by:=if (
                ID is NULL,
                overlay_nearest (@layer, ID, filter:=ID is not NULL)[0],
                ID
            )
        )
        ,0.52
    )
)
```